# How to work with src file and keep the directory clean (from compiled files)?

Tags: javascript, webpack, src

The reason to have **src** and **dist** folders is pretty clear: we change source code commit it to repository and use compiled **dist** files for production.
But what could you recommend for development? We still want to keep src clean from compiled file and make it very fast to review the changes.

Before we just transpiled SAAS into CSS and put it into source and keep JS files as they are(without compiling in one file or coping them to dist). And now we decided to rethink the concept.

we are doing web development, but I think question is more broad.

Comment: Did you try webpack-dev-server ?

Comment: yes, but it compiles all the files right?

Comment: @STEVER yeah but the dev server stores/serves compiled files to/from memory, not disk. [Read this](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html)

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood, you are looking for a development architecture/workflow to directly serve you sources to the browser (and use DevTools edition features btw). In fact, there are 2 things to do to achieve this.

1) For compiled/transpiled languages (**SAAS**, **LESS**, **TypeScript**, ...) and unsupported languages (ES6, ES7), you will need to compile/transpile them on the client side. Tools like **LESS.js**, **typescript.js**, **BabelJS**  are great to do that. I don't know any SAAS compiler implementation in Javascript.

2) Then, you need 2 different html indexes. For example `index.hml` for production and `dev.html` for development.

`index.html` with bundled (dist) files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/app.bundle.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/app.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

`dev.html` with all sources (src) files:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>App Title (Dev)</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="src/file1.less" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/file1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/file2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="src/file3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/less.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

This way, developers access the web app using, let's say **http://localhost/dev.html** and can enjoy all the goodness to have sources right in the browser. Without taking care of the compilation.

> To apply such an architecture you may need to adapt client and/or server code and also build tools to work in both mode (prod and dev).

Hope I helped.